# Triggering web page input text change for search results in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to write JavaScript code in `Tampermonkey` that will simulate entering search text in a dynamic (search results update with each letter typed) web site search box. The HTML for the search element is as follows:

```
<input class="billybudd" id="search" placeholder="Search" 
        autocomplete="off" type="search" value="" data-reactid="rotterdam">
```

I have made this work for other sites by using the following code:

```
$('#search').val('searchtext');
$('#search').change();
```

For this site, though, the search `text box` updates with the `'searchtext'` value, but the dynamic search results are not triggered by the `change()` method.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the code that is assigning the change event handler to the control?

Comment: How do I locate that? Forgive me, I'm a learning newb.

Comment: I am becoming more familiar with Google Chrome Development Tools, though, and should understand any help you provide.

Comment: There are two event listeners that are unique to this control, **reset** and **submit**. I tried putting `$('#search').trigger("submit");` into my code, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Okay, I have identified some Javascript behind the control in question. It is  as follows:

Comment: @taxicala I had more to explain, so I added more in another answer. I'd really appreciate more help. It seems like I'm close.

Answer (score 1):

I will jump to an empty pool here and do a wild guess, perhaps the event bound is `input` and not `change` so that each keypress will trigger the search functionality, try as follows:

```
$('#search').val('searchtext');
$('#search').trigger("input");
```